# Grails projects often become unconfigured in eclipse after I restart my machine

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

I have little experience in Java/Groovy/Grails, about 1 year using Eclipse and some weeks using [GGTS](http://grails.org/products/ggts), and I always got my projects with build path problems, or other related problems, with apparently no reason. The environment seems to be buggy. Any tip?

Below there's an screenshot of a project I was working on and, after a computer restart, a lot of wild build path problems had appeared.
[image: A example]

PS.: To solve these problems I closed the project in GGTS, used a `grails clean` in console, opened the project again (all the problems still were there), then I just **gave a look** into `properties > Java Build Path` and all problems have gone. These steps makes no sense for me.

Comment: I have started to face the similar problem in Eclipse Juno but it disappears when I do replace contents from Repository.

Comment: I dont know the answer to your question, however my opinion is to dump GGTS and get Intellij IDEA.

Comment: @JamesKleeh That kind of problem happens too when using Eclipse using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others I would not recommend Eclipse. All variants(sts,ggts,vanilla eclipse+plugins) are unstable at least on Juno, IMHO.

I personally use emacs, but like @James, I would suggest IntelliJ:

- stable as in no strange internal errors pop up while doing Grails coding, no project corruptions.
- better completion, especially dynamic methods